# How to log when jwt expired in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, jwt

I want to log user when logged-in and logged-out, and in also when jwt token expired. To do this requirement i call `loginHistoryService.saveUserLogout()` when `ExpiredJwtException` occurs, but the problem is that this method called more than one, because the when user opens the form, this form contains a lots of ajax requests, so each request cause to go to this filter and log user logout multiple times.
Is there a better way to implement this requirement?

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (!request.getRequestURI().contains("/signout")) {
            try {
                if (checkJWTToken(request)) {
                    Claims claims = validateToken(request);
                    if (claims.get(CLAIM_AUTHORITIES_KEY) != null) {
                        setUpSpringAuthentication(claims);
                    }
                    else {
                        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                }
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                // call log method here, but this method called more than one
                loginHistoryService.saveUserLogout();
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                response.setHeader("ExpiredJwt", "true");
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Your JWT token expired!");
            } catch (UnsupportedJwtException | MalformedJwtException e) {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "forbidden!");
            }
        }
        else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

The purpose of `loginHistoryService` is store `LoginHistory` object with below declaration:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_login_history")
public class LoginHistory extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    @Column(name = "user_name", nullable = false)
    private String userName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "is_success", nullable = false)
    private boolean success;

    @Column(name = "is_login", nullable = false)
    private boolean login;

    @Column(name = "browser_type")
    private BrowserType browserType;

    @Column(name = "browser_name")
    private String browserName;

    @Column(name = "operating_system_type")
    private OperatingSystemType operatingSystemType;

    @Column(name = "operating_system_name")
    private String operatingSystemName;

    @Column(name = "login_failure_reason")
    private LoginFailureReason loginFailureReason;
}
```

That audits user logins and logouts.

**UPDATE 2**

I changed `LoginHistory` and added `jwtToken` field to store jwt and check if a record exists, then do not insert. but the problem is that it the records inserted multiple time.

```
@Service
public class LoginHistoryService implements ILoginHistoryService {

    @Autowired
    private ILoginHistoryRepository loginHistoryRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveLogWhenExpiredUser(String token) {
        if (!loginHistoryRepository.checkExpiredTokenExistence(token)) {
            // save the log record
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the method that checks record existence:

```
@Override
public boolean checkExpiredTokenExistence(String token) {
    String hql =    " select cast((case when count(*) = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as boolean) " +
                    " from " + domainClass.getName() + " e " +
                    " where e.jwtToken = :jwtToken " +
                    "   and e.logoutType = :logoutType " ;

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("jwtToken", token.getBytes());
    params.put("logoutType", LogOutType.Expired);

    return super.find(hql, params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> because the when user opens the form, this form contains a lots of
> assets and ajax requests, so each request cause to go to this filter
> and log user logout multiple times

Your public assets must not be taken into account by your security filter. Kindly ignore security check on your public assets

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault and updated a question. I ignored assets, but what can i do with multiple ajax requests?

Comment: What is the purspose of your `loginHistoryService.saveUserLogout()` ? To log the user in ?

Comment: In your class `LoginHistory` you can for instance add a certain field `jwt` which log the user with specific jwt token. Check for duplicates and save the activity only if no records of the current token is found

Comment: Thanks @dm_tr, It came to my mind but i want to know is there a better way or also another concept to implement this requirement or not?

Comment: Maybe there is a better way to do it. But semantically this is also a good method

Comment: Dear @dm_tr check my second update, please.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a constraint on uniqueness of `jwtToken` and `logoutType`:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints={
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"jwtToken", "logoutType"})
}, name = "tbl_login_history")
public class LoginHistory extends BaseEntity<Long> {
    ...
}
```